# SharePoint 2010 Issue with CSV File

Tags: 2010, excel, csv

We are using SharePoint 2010.  I have permission (full access) on my site. I have three uploaded files (one Word .doc, one Excel .xls, one CSV .csv).

I had no problems editing Word and Excel files.  But I could not edit CSV file.  Even "Edit Document" button on CSV file was disabled (greyed off).  The file is a read-only file.

Could anyone help me on this issue?  Why does CSV file have difference behavior from other file formats in SharePoint?  I tried to search but could not find anything from the web.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to DOCICON.XML (default location is C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\XML)

```
<Mapping Key="csv" Value="icxltx.png" OpenControl=""/>
```

Then in IIS Manager select the server and then select MIME Types, update the entry for csv to 'application/vnd.ms-excel'.

This will allow you to click the file name link and have the file open in Excel however the edit document button will still be disabled.

Source: http://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2011/01/05/sharepoint-opening-csv-files-with-microsoft-excel/ (Nick Grattan’s SharePoint Blog)

Comment: Thanks quila Sands! How can I make the Edit Document enabled for CSV file? Any suggestions? Thanks a lot. YK

Comment: @Yan. That will require some custom development to create an OpenDocuments control that knows how to handle a csv file. You could then specify this control in the OpenControl attribute of the Mapping XML element. This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/malag/archive/2010/05/13/using-custom-opendocuments-control-to-open-custom-file-types-in-sharepoint.aspx) has more info and a project that can provide a starting point.

Comment: Thank you very much Aquila Sands! After copy over xls's mapping then change xls to csv:
<Mapping Key="csv" Value="icxltx.png" OpenControl="SharePoint.OpenDocuments"/>. CSV files now are editable from SharePoint. Issue resolved!

Comment: Please mark the answer appropriately so anyone could benefit from!